# file not found: logging.properties

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, exception, gwt

i get the following exception in my GWT/GAE-Maven-project:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/.../war/WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

How can i fix that problem and what's the usage of this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"logging.properties" is the configuration file for java.util.logging (generic java logging). GWT can use this to provide client side logging support but it needs to be activated. Check your GWT module files (*.gwt.xml) for

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

If that inherits isn't present then something else in your stack is trying to use logging and cannot find the config file. App Engine (GAE) can also use java logging. If all else fails just throw an empty logging.properties file in your WEB-INF and configure it later.

I am sure you will want to configure proper logging in your project at some point. If you are doing a GWT/GAE project then I would recommend just using java.util.logging. It tends to be the simplest to configure with that stack. There is also Log4J and Slf4J which are pretty popular but they take a few more steps to configure and use with GWT/GAE. That's just my opinion though. Other may disagree.